# rails 3 routing not working as i would like

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

How would i go about routing the default page in my rails application to :

http://localhost:3000/pages/1

at the moment in my routes file i have:-

```
root :to => 'pages#show'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the id param like:

```
root :to => 'pages#show', :id => 1
```